# Coimage of a $G$-linear map as a sub representation of its domain

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading an introduction on Representation theory, in particular about $G$-linear maps.

Suppose $(V,\rho),(W,\sigma)$ - $V,W$ finite dimensional complex vector spaces - are representations of a group $G$, and $\varphi\colon V \rightarrow W$ a $G$-linear map (equivariant map). It is mentioned that the kernel of $\varphi$ is a $G$-submodule of $V$ and that image and cokernel of $\varphi$ are $G$-submodules of $W$. What about the coimage $V/\ker \varphi$?

I have tried to check if it is a $G$-submodule of $V$ and it seems so. It is a vector space, and if $[v] = v+\ker \varphi \in V/\ker \varphi$ and $g \in G$, then 
$$g[v] = gv+g\ker \varphi = gv+\ker \varphi \in V/\ker \varphi $$
as $V$ is a $G$-module and $\ker \varphi$ is a $G$-submodule of $V$. Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes if $U\subseteq V$ is a $G$-submodule then $V/U$ is a $G$-module.

Comment: Are you asking if $V/\ker\varphi$ is a **submodule** of $V$ or just if it has a $G$-module structure? To be a submodule of $V$, do you actually mean does $\ker\varphi$ have a **complement** in $V$? If so, yes by Maschke's theorem.

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps at this stage my terminology should be more refined. I am studying the basic definitions of the subject anyway. In my understanding, a $G$-submodule of a $G$-module $V$ is a linear subspace of $V$ which is a $G$-module itself. I am not sure if the word 'submodule' means actually something else. Maybe I should use the word 'subrepresentation', shouldn't I? If you could help me clarifying this I would be grateful.

Comment: Then I think your question should be rephrased. (think: it doesn't make sense to call a quotient vector space a subspace, and similarly it doesn't make sense to call a quotient module a submodule). But you are correct that the quotient of a $G$-module by a submodule has a natural $G$-module structure.

Comment: So it is not correct to say 'submodule', but I guess 'subrepresentation' is more proper. Is that right?

Comment: No, neither of those are right. A quotient module is not the same as a submodule, or in rep terminology, a quotient representation is not the same as a subrepresentation. To wit, $V/\ker\phi$ is not a submodule / subrepresentation of $V$ and $W/{\rm img}\phi$ is not a submodule / subrepresentation of $W$. (Although if $V$ and $W$ are semisimple, these quotients will be *isomorphic* to submodules / subrepresentations of the originals.)